# JetBrains .icls color scheme editor

Tags: themes, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Does there exist any proper `.icls` editor for editing JetBrains WebStorm/Phpstorm **color config** files?
Editor can be of any kind, Web-based, standalone etc.
Thanks

Comment: It is... **built-in**? -- `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts`

Comment: @LazyOne It isn't much feature-full and difficult.

Comment: There is simply nothing else available, unless someone has written that for himself .. which I very doubt considering that it's a pretty complex task when 1) no official docs available (what styles are available (their names)); sure -- you can check source code, but that is for few languages only, for PHP it's not an option; 2) (very) limited scope of application (not many people creating themes on regular base); 3) You need to restart an IDE to see external changes in those config files (this is MUCH longer that making them in actual Settings screen); 4) Styles do change from time to time